# Android Activity as a dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I have an Activity named `whereActity` which has child dialogs as well. Now, I want to display this activity as a dialog for another activity.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: If you just want loading dialog, you can use [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Answer (score 578, accepted):

To start activity as dialog I defined it like this in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Use this property inside your `activity` tag to avoid that your Dialog appears in the recently used apps list

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

If you want to stop your dialog / activity from being destroyed when the user clicks outside of the dialog:

After `setContentView()` in your `Activity` use:

`this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);`

Now when I call `startActivity()` it displays as a dialog, with the previous activity shown when the user presses the back button.

Note that if you are using `ActionBarActivity` (or AppCompat theme), you'll need to use `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` instead.

Comment: Using the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" is the way to go but don't forget to use excludeFromRecents=true or else your dialog will appear in the Recently Used Apps (hold the Home key).

Comment: I've also had difficulty with the size of the dialog if using LinearLayout as the root layout.  Using RelativeLayout helps if you're going to be setting requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) or getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)

Comment: i have difficulty related to the activity as dialog..
i made the activity as dialog but the problem is when i click outside the the activity it automatically get closed..???
is there any solution related to this..??????

Comment: @Emmanuel, it has to be android:excludeFromRecents="true" note the double quotes

Comment: I want to add additional codes for who want activity dialog more wider.. Add this after setContentView() , getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Comment: Can we also embed ActionBar using this way ?

Comment: Note that if you are using ActionBarActivity (or AppCompat theme), you'll need to use `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`

Comment: @Wolverine, Add `this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);` after `setContentView()` method to prevent the activity from being destroyed when you click outside the dialog you created.

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Dialog').

Comment: @QuentinKlein lets say we are an sdk, projects import us as a library, how we can know if they are using actionbaractivity or appcompat activity, thanks :)

Comment: @Mike I don't think you can know that, but I'll advise always using AppCompat because it is retroactive and can work for everyone, but the other choice won't

Comment: @QuentinKlein I can not find this theme you suggest: `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`

Comment: @SayedAbolfazlFatemi note that you have to import Support Libraries v7 `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1` (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html)

Comment: Screen rotation has no effect. However I've different layouts in layout and layout-land folders.

Comment: Is it possible to send the data from Dialog Activity to the Parent Activity when i close the Dialog Activity.

Comment: Is this how logging in on to Google Games work for leaderboards and achievements? How secure is this for passing sensitive information between apps?

Answer (score 45):

Use this code so that the dialog activity won't be closed when the user touches outside the dialog box:

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

requires API level 11

Comment: Is there any solution for API < 11 ?

Comment: @pkgupta, if it is acceptable to you, you should not worry at least API <15 for me since there is not much people using those earlier versions anyway. In fact, as of 2017, I think 19 or 20 is the new minSDK.

Answer (score 32):

You can define this style in values/styles.xml to perform a more former Splash :

```
   <style name="Theme.UserDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/trans</item>
    </style>
```

And use it AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="sensor"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.UserDialog">
```

Comment: re `@drawable/trans`: you should be able to use `@android:color/transparent` which would create a `ColorDrawable` to use as backgrounds.

Comment: <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> is another alternative

Comment: The problem is that the activity is filling the whole screen but not showing as dialog overlay.

Comment: It is `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`  (no "android").  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33738675/7292819).  Not sure about the other items.

Answer (score 26):

If you need Appcompat Version

style.xml

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

yourmanifest.xml

```
    <activity
          android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/title"
          android:theme="@style/AppDialogTheme">
    </activity>
```

Comment: This is great. I needed to remove the action bar. I had to modify the XML slightly though. I had to add `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` to make it work for me. I also added `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` for good measure.

Comment: Also for me  `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`did not work (Android 5.0.1), and I had to change to `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Answer (score 23):

1 - You can use the same activity as both dialog and full screen, dynamically:

Call `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog)` before calling `setContentView(...)` and `super.oncreate()` in your Activity.

2 - If you don't plan to change the activity theme style you can use

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

(as mentioned by @faisal khan)

Comment: Just a note: when I use the programmatic method (the first method), everything behind the dialog box is blacked out completely; this was not an issue in the other method though. Too bad...I really wanted to do it programmatically....Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1

Comment: @Eric did you find solution for blacked out??

Comment: @anand yes, combining both solutions together fixes the blackout issue: set theme of activity to a dialog theme in android manifest (`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`) and programmatically set theme of activity to a dialog or an activity in onCreate https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915764/2898715

Answer (score 17):

If your activity is being rendered as a dialog, simply add a button to your activity's xml,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/close_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Dismiss" />
```

Then attach a click listener in your Activity's Java code. In the listener, simply call `finish()`

```
Button close_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close_button);
close_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

That should dismiss your dialog, returning you to the calling activity.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to remove activity header & provide a custom view for the dialog add the following to the activity block of you manifest

```
android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
```

and design your activity_layout with your desired view

Answer (score 4):

Create activity as dialog,  Here is Full Example

[image]

1. AndroidManife.xml

   `<activity android:name=".appview.settings.view.DialogActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"/>`
2. DialogActivity.kt

   ```
   class DialogActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog)
       this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true)

       btnOk.setOnClickListener {
         finish()
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. activity_dialog.xml

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#0072ff"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="@dimen/_300sdp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
           style="@style/normal16Style"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:paddingTop="20dp"
           android:paddingBottom="20dp"
           android:text="Download"
           android:textColorHint="#FFF" />

       <View
           android:id="@+id/viewDivider"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="2dp"
           android:background="#fff"
           android:backgroundTint="@color/white_90"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/txtTitle" />

       <TextView
           style="@style/normal14Style"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:paddingTop="20dp"
           android:paddingBottom="20dp"
           android:text="Your file is download"
           android:textColorHint="#FFF" />


       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnOk"
           style="@style/normal12Style"
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
           android:background="@drawable/circle_corner_layout"
           android:text="Ok"
           android:textAllCaps="false" />
       </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: Please don't use x-large fonts to make your answer look weird.

Answer (score 2):

Set the theme in your android manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

And set the dialog state on touch to finish.

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some times you can get the Exception which is given below

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.**

So for resolving you can use simple solution

add theme of you activity in manifest as dialog for appCompact.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
```

It can be helpful for somebody.