# Single dialog application

Tags: android, dialog

I have an android application where all the logic is in a dialog box. How do I just have this dialog as the activity and avoid creating a normal activity/view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `Activity` have a `Dialog` theme placing this in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Similar question: [Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1979369/119895).