# How can I show an intent in a new Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

I have a little problem with an intent that call an Activity that show a chart. I want to show the activity in a new Dialog, how can I make it?

this is the code that call the Activity:

```
    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(
            chartproject.this, buildBarDataset(titles, values),
            renderer, Type.STACKED);    
    chartproject.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You might find your answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make change in AndroidManifest.xml as shown below,

```
<activity android:name=".className"
              android:label="Choose Category..."
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustPan"  
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">   </activity>
```

where,

className: main class name of activity that you want to show in dialog.

that's it.
you will have your activity as dialog.

Comment: it works, thanks :)  but now... How add a button to the dialog?

Comment: Create new xml file for the layout of activity. place the button on that xml. In setContentView() method of a class, use this xml file. By the way i can help you in learning android.

Comment: @user609239 This only works if your activity extend Activity. How can you achieve this effect if you extends ActionBarActivity? In my case I cant extend Activity. The whole framework is build on top of  ActionBarActivity... No way to extend Activity.