# Setup schedule to start an Activity by user

Tags: android, time, android-activity

Is there a way to start an activity in real time? For example I want to start the GPS when the time is 12:25PM? But I want the time to be selected by the user.

For example we have an activity that takes the desired time (11:45AM) from the user and the next activity is started when the time is 11:45?

Comment: You mean setup a schedule to run an activity by user?

Comment: yes something like that

Answer (score 0):

After the user enters the time, use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set up an alarm for that time.

Then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050027/how-do-you-start-an-activity-with-alarmmanager-in-android) on how to start your activity once the alarm is set.