# Alarm manager to start activity at given time by user

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to start a service at a particular time and want the user to select the time and date i have created one with alarm manager but want the user to enter time in that..kindly help thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you start an Activity with AlarmManager in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050027/how-do-you-start-an-activity-with-alarmmanager-in-android)

Comment: Submit your work first. Then we can help you.