# Is there a way to open a browser tab automatically in Android?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to open a browser at a specific link automatically at a give time / daily.

Maybe there is some kind of script, add-on for bowser but I still haven't find one.

Does anyone know a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use an `AalarmManager`  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) is an example

And then here is the code you should execute

```
String urlString = "your_url";
Intent intent = new 
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));


intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome"); 
    try { 
    context.startActivity(intent); 
    } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) { 
     context.startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this is a combination of three things, setting the alarm, firing the intent and making sure the intent has the data to open a specific uri in the browser.

[start activity from an alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050027/how-do-you-start-an-activity-with-alarmmanager-in-android)

[open a uri](http://String%20url%20=%20%22http://www.stackoverflow.com%22;%20Intent%20i%20=%20new%20Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);%20i.setData(Uri.parse(url));%20startActivity(i);%20Intent%20intent%20=%20new%20Intent(Intent.%20...%20Intent%20intent%20=%20new%20Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,%20Uri.parse(%22http://www.stackoverflow.com%22));%20startActivity(intent);%20startActivity(new%20Intent(Intent.)