# How to automatically awake the application in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alarmmanager, alarm

I am coding an alarm on my own and I would like that the alarm would wake up the phone and show the Alert Dialog. Can someone give me some insight on how to do this please?

Comment: The alert, inputs, and everything else is ok. I only need to wake the phone at a desired time(this time is on me and is ok too).

Comment: Please specify your problem and give a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hey Ling...sorry but I can't...but It works like this I have an alarm time set by someone and it must show an Alert dialog when the time is come. I can't find something to run in the background till timeNow and alarm time aer the same and wake the screen with the alert and its functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [android_alarm_maganer](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) to achive what you need. Simply run it every second or so and check if DateTime.now() meets your criteria.

Example:

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';

void checkAlarms() {
  if(DateTime().now == alarm){
   //Do something
  }
}

main() async {
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(...);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), helloAlarmID, checkAlarms);
}
```

Then you can run another Activity as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050027/how-do-you-start-an-activity-with-alarmmanager-in-android)