# inside Android Dialog, how to setup onActivityResult for startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

From an activity, I can easily setup the `onActivityResult()` and call `startActivityForResult()` and everything works fine.

Now, I need to call `startActivityForResult()` from the Dialog.   But I can't setup the `onActivityResult()`, I believe `Dialog` is not an `Activity`.

How do I get the result?

I try something like this inside a dialog but it failed.

```
//create new Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, m_PicUri);
((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, Const.TAKE_PIC_ACTIVITY_RET_CODE);
```

Comment: Provide code of creating and starting dialog please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your dialog is a dialog fragment you can use

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent);
```

in this way the result is sent to the activity that created the dialog

Answer (score 5):

You can declare your `Activity` to have a `Dialog` theme.  Look into this SO question: [Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

You would change this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

You should be able to use `startActivityForResult()` like normal.  I know the `BluetoothChat` example Android program uses something similar to return the Bluetooth device that you choose from a `Dialog` list.

Comment: This should be marked as answer.This is the only way of doing what you are expecting anyway.

Comment: This is not answer. The question is "How to startActivityForResult() from dialog". But not "How to declare activity as dialog."

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead of Dialog. Because The dialog is secondary to its activity. When you start the activity with startActivityForResult(), your dialog gets dismissed

**Another Example Use Callback**

Create **Interface**

```
 public interface DialogCallback {
   void getResults(String results);
 }
```

Create **DialogFragment**

```
public class DialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

DialogCallback dialogCallback;

public DialogFragment setCallBack(DialogCallback dialogCallback){
    this.dialogCallback = dialogCallback;
    return this;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    dialogCallback.getResults("hello");
}

}
```

In your **Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     new DialogFragment().setCallBack(dialogCallback).show(getFragmentManager(),"");
}

DialogCallback dialogCallback = new DialogCallback() {
    @Override
    public void getResults(String results) {
        if(results!=null){
            Log.e(TAG,results);
        }
    }
};
```

**Output**

When you dismiss the **DialogFragment** you will see the **"hello"** Log in your **Activity**

Answer (score 1):

Use the compatibility package then build your dialog using DialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

On the dialog constructor pass the reference of parent Activity, then you can use in the dialog like this,

```
parentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
```