# ANDROID: How can I launch a popup dialog from an notification or long-pressed search button on top of all windows?

Tags: android, search, dialog, popup, notifications

I have searched and everything is about launching an activity not a dialog.

What I want to do is to display a notification in the status bar, and when the user presses it a dialog pops up on top of whatever the user was viewing before s/he clicked the notification. I dont want the dialog to show on top of the main activity or the recent apps list.

Also, how can i launch the dialog from long pressing the search button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm copying from here: [Here is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog:)

to Start activity as dialog i defined

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

now when i `startActivity()` it display like dialog and parent activity display on back, i wan a button to whom i click dialog should dismiss and parent activity should display without refreshing the page.

And then somebody added the comment:

Using the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` is the way to go but don't forget to use `excludeFromRecents=true` or else your dialog will appear in the Recently Used Apps (hold the Home key).

And for the long press, override `onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` and you can make the long press do what you want.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Thanks so much this is totally awesome!