# Why can't we open a dialog from another dialog? What is the technical challenge?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to open a dialog from listener of another dialog in service. But As soon as i dismiss first dialog nothing happen, not even a crash , neither the second dialog shows up

Comment: There's no technical reason to not be able to open one `Dialog` from the callback of another. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display Android dialog on top of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424757/display-android-dialog-on-top-of-another)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible to open dialog from another dialog,
Use this code to open first dialog,
here dialog_inventory_search file is first dialog layout file,**

```
val dialog1 = Dialog(activity!!, R.style.my_dialog)
     dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
     dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_inventory_search)
     val btnSearch = dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch)
```

here is first dialog button click listener,

```
btnSearch .setOnClickListener {
                       val dialog2 = Dialog(activity!!, R.style.my_dialog)
                        dialog2.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
                        dialog2.setCancelable(false)
                        dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_search)
                        dialog2.show()
                }
                            dialog1.show()
```