# Android dialog show top view

Tags: android, dialog

Android various dialog boxes will pop up in an interface. How can I ensure that one dialog box is on top of all other dialog boxes，we set

```
 dialog.window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FIRST_APPLICATION_WINDOW)
```

is not working

Comment: There isn't any particular solution available for android as of now. But you can create a custom layout for dialog. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425019/11555065)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Show one dialog box at a time, take input from the user and move to the next one.

Comment: he dialog box is asynchronous. Our project has a forced update dialog box. In order to ensure that users can force the update, when the forced dialog box pops up, other dialog boxes can only be displayed at the bottom