# Bring view to focus like dialog Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to bring a view to focus just like an `AlertDialog`. How can I do this ?

P.S: My view is fairly complex and hence, I'm using a FrameLayout as suggested in [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).

Comment: If you want like `Alert Dialog` why not use it? you can always give your custom layout to your `Alert Dialog`

Comment: I tried using `AlertDialog` but that doesn't seem to work !

Comment: what does not work? you can share your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I've show complex View in Dialog, I prefer to put whole view in XML and then Make a new Activity and set the content view of Activity to that XML and then start activity as Dialog by this

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Have a look at the post

[Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

it is fairly easy and simple and straight forward, Hope this helps!