# open pdf in popup android

Tags: android, pdf, popup

I am developing an Android app, where I need to open my pdf file in a popup window.
My code is:

```
ImageView brobutton=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
brobutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                                   }
});
```

I already have developed an app to open pdf in emulator with this code:

```
final String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
WebView mWebView=new WebView(SubProducts.this);                                         mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){                                                          
        view.loadUrl(image_urlpdf);
        return false; // then it is not handled by default action
    }
});
mWebView.loadUrl((googleDocsUrl + image_urlpdf));
```

under the onclick of button I need to open my pdf.Any one suggest me with good idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your app to open PDF. Either pass some flag using intents to alert that your app need to open popup for showing PDF.

Check this thread for how to show activity as dialog [Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

Comment: thanq sulabh gupta.passing intent from dialog is same as passing intent from class i.e., like intent intent=new Intent(Present.this,forward.class);startActivity(intent);

Comment: Yes, You can use following code in your first app to call second app (which is opening PDF file) 



    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("isDialog", true);
    startActivity(intent)


And in your second app which is showing PDF, you can get it like

    getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isDialog");

Comment: @ sulabh Gupta..I have followed your code.but it is not opening in pop up.wats wrong???

Comment: @SHAIKAFEEZA : have you changed the activity style in manifest for showing dialog?   like **<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />**  This theme is required to show activity as dialog. You can also set it from code file like **setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);** I hope you have not overridden any other theme for that activity in code.

Comment: yes Sulabh Gupta i did that.It is not showing any thing.i.e.,just showing activity name.I did the "pdf regarding" code under onCreate but still not opening.

Comment: Are you able to see blank dialog? If so, check your code to read PDF file. And you can remove activity name by using **requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)**

Comment: thanq Sulabh Gupta.Iam using same code as posted in question to open pdf.And that code exactly works for me to open pdf with out dialog.plz have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You could load your PDF file in the custom dialog.
Tutorial for creating the custom dialog - http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: thanq naveen.Ok with custo dialogue but how to open pdf under that??

Comment: As you mentioned in the question you are loading a PDF file in a webview, in the same way you could create a webview in the custom dialog and display the PDF.

Comment: can you provide me how to start pdf activity in dialog with example?