# Null Pointer error when trying to utilize a class with AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-widget, scrollwheel

Trying to inflate an `AlertDialog.Builder`. I'm trying to get the date wheel (Yuri Kanivets' wheel) to appear inside of my dialog. Since the exact code that I need exists inside one of his classes, I'm just trying to instantiate a new instance of his `DateActivity` class (which I've imported into my project), and then add that to my dialog. Unfortunately, I can't seem to connect my `DateActivity` object with my dialog. I thought that it would be one of the arguments where I inflate the view, but that crashes. Here's my code:

EDIT: To clarify, in the code that follows there are no errors. The problem as I mentioned is that there is no usage, and therefore no connection, of my `DateActivity` variable with the `AlertDialog.Builder`. I've tried using that variable (dateWheelSelector) as an argument to builderView and also to the builder variable instantiations, but both of these crash. I need to figure out how to connect these since right now my dialog is empty.

```
private void setStartDate() {

    //somehow I need to use this variable, but where???
    DateActivity dateWheelSelector = new DateActivity();

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View builderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wheel_date_layout, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(builderView);       
    alert = builder.create();

    /* Set the title of this dialog programatically */
    TextView title = (TextView) builderView.findViewById(R.id.date_title);
    title.setText("Choose Start Date");

    alert.show();
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: the snippet looks good. Post the logcat error

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. See my edit above. Thanks!

Comment: the you have not NPE?

Comment: post the DateActivity class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add an Activity to a dialog. You can either define the Activity to be a Dialog (see [Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)) or you can refactor your DateActivity to be a DialogFragment (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) that can be used as Fragment or as Dialog.

Comment: Or you could also refactor your DateActivity to be a custom View and add it one time to an Activity and the other time to a Dialog.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll look into these. I was afraid that might be the case.