# Creating bodyless activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Currently I am trying to make an activity that can be moved on the screen , in other words this activity can float on the screen.  I know I am missing something that should be added to achieve this functionality.

What should I do to achieve floating activity which can be moved around anywhere on the screen?

Comment: Float above other apps or just float above the background?

Comment: free float above background.

Comment: I think for something like this you are better off using a `Fragment`. I say this is because the only logical reason you would want that is to be able to see other things behind it. Creating a standalone fragment that floats is much better design than using an `Activity`. Just some advice.

Comment: fine but fragment is an extension of activity. By default it also takes up the whole screen and can't float around. Well if fragment works better in such cases, I will use fragments but I want to know how can I make a free floating app

Comment: SYSTEM_OVERLAY allows you to float above other apps. You want `android:windowIsTranslucent` in the theme of your activity (so that you Activity window is transparent, you don't need to make a new one). Then you have a choice - either keep the activity full screen and move Views in it (easy) or resize and move the actual window (hard). (Fragments are irrelevant to the discussion in my humble opinion)

Comment: the easy part has already been done :). The question is about free floating activity i-e; Moving around a window

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to do something similar to the Facebook chat circles (where you have a view on top of other apps) then take a look here: http://www.cloudinfy.com/2013/06/android-chat-head-view-like-in-facebook.html

Basically you need to start a service and add a view to the window manager.

---

If you're looking to simply create an activity to look like a dialog then have a look here: [Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

This is very similar to a normal activity but the theme is set to Theme.Dialog

Answer (score 0):

There's a good solution here: http://cases.azoft.com/android-tutorial-floating-activity/ 
They just add an attribute to the theme of a tablet Activity:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

If any problems on KitKat devices, add some lines to the theme:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>  
<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>  
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>  
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```