# How to manage a back stack within a dialog on android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can a dialog on an android tablet manage its own back stack? In other words: Can you show multiple levels of navigation within a dialog?

On iPad, this is a very common design pattern: A sheet or popover with a navigation bar on top.

When I try this on android (using Fragments) I only have one FragmentManager: the one from the hosting FragmentActivity. I can push multiple dialog fragments on its back stack. The visual effect of such a push, is that one dialog (A) disappears and another one (B) appears. As the user taps 'back', B will disappear again, and A will re-appear again. That is usable, but I was hoping for a smoother transition that feels more like a single context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Dialog` is a sub-window within an `Activity` so no, the framework doesn't manage back stacks for `Dialog`s automatically for you.

What you can do instead is use an activity and give it a dialog theme. This activity will look like a dialog (i.e. translucent background, etc.) but it will have all of the capabilities of a normal activity. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1979369/844882).

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: It works indeed. But it is not ideal that you have to manage the dialog size yourself and write your own response to orientation changes.

Comment: What do you mean the "dialog size"? My answer suggests that you don't use a dialog... but instead an `Activity` that merely looks like a dialog.

Comment: Alex: I meant the perceived dialog size. I suppose window size is technically more accurate.

Comment: @KrisVanBael Have you looked at the available dialog themes in [`android.R.style`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)? For example, the `Theme_Holo_DialogWhenLarge` theme is one I usually use.

Comment: I'm targeting API 11. So no Holo. But that's okay. I think I got it all to behave correctly.