# HTML Rendering for custom browser window on Android

Tags: android, webview, webkit, chromium, gecko

As I understand it, you can't use WebView on the home screen. I'm looking to have an app built (I'm not building it, but paying someone on Elance to do it. I just want to reduce that person's research time) that puts up a "pop-up" window on the homescreen. Inside this window should be an HTML5 app. The the window has to support full HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

At this point I am assuming we have to built a complete custom "browser window". Is that a correct assumption?

Does anyone have experience with this? I've looked into GeckoView, WebKit, and Chromium, but, as I'm not an Android developer, unsure if either of these support what I'm trying to get done.

Any help/hint/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a popup window on the homescreen?

Comment: Sure. NOT a widget. It will be similar to the apps that pop up a window with a newly received text message. The appear regardless of what home screen you're on.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a window that appears on top of whatever you're doing, be it home screen or another app, you could certainly just use a `WebView`. You just need to put it on an `Activity` with a transparent background, no title bar, etc. This is mostly easily done by [theming it as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog).

Comment: Interesting. If the WebView takes 50% of the screen, is the background still "navigatable"? As in, can I swipe left and right to move around on my home screen?