# android dialog single choice change items search

Tags: android, search, android-alertdialog

I'm in an Android project.

I want to show a AlertDialog on which the user can pick one item (about 100 items, it's dynamic). I want to add the possibility of searching also.
My real problem is that it seems I can't change the items once the Dialog is created.
The creation code:

```
// The List with the beaches with radio buttons, single choice!
public void showBeachesDialog(final Activity context, boolean isFromZonas)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    searchAdapter = new SearchDialogAdapater(orderedBeaches, orderedBeachesIds, context);

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(searchAdapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            index = which;
            if (!((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).isEnabled())
                ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
        }
    });     

    DialogOkOnClickListener listener = new DialogOkOnClickListener(context, isFromZonas);

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.searchOK, listener);

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            // User cancelled the dialog: nothing happens
        }
    });

    builder.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_beach));
    builder.setTitle(StaticUtils.DIALOG_TITLE);

    View dialogView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_beaches, null);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.search_beach);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchQueryListener(searchAdapter));      

    builder.setView(dialogView);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
}
```

So, now I have the dialog with all the elements I want (the SearchDialogAdapater is fine).
The DialogOnClickListener is also working.
The search view is appearing on the dialog, and my SearchQueryListener is working perfectly, so I won't post here the code, but in Debug I can see that if I type "d" the elements without the "d" are filtered out.

Now I would like to not throw away all the code and find a way to change the items of the dialog without showing a new one...

Sorry for long question and if there is a obvious way I am missing...

Thank you all.

Comment: perhaps you should create an activity itself which will be a dialog activity... check this link for more references:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, but I really want to use a dialog and not an Activity, altough it seems to be harder...

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using a class that implements 4 interfaces so it can handles everything that I want.

The code is now like this, hope it's useful to someone who want to make its own Dialog with personalized search.

```
public void showBeachesDialog(final Activity context, boolean isFromZonas)
```

{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

```
searchAdapter = new SearchDialogAdapater
    (orderedBeaches, orderedBeachesIds, context, isFromZonas);

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(searchAdapter, -1, null);
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.searchOK, searchAdapter);
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, null);
builder.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_beach));
builder.setTitle(StaticUtils.DIALOG_TITLE);

View dialogView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate
    (R.layout.dialog_beaches, null);

SearchView searchView = SearchView)dialogView.findViewById
(R.id.search_beach);

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchAdapter);

builder.setView(dialogView);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

dialog.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(searchAdapter);
searchAdapter.setDialog(dialog);
dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

}

The orderedBeaches and orderedBeachesIds are String[] and int[], my data to display. 
Below is my adapter which uses a stack to handle the items available at any moment of the searching:

```
public class SearchDialogAdapater implements ListAdapter, OnQueryTextListener,
OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener {
protected Stack<String[]> stackBeaches;
protected Stack<int[]> stackBeachesIds;

protected Activity context;
protected TreeMap<String, Integer> orderedBeaches;

protected ListView listView;

protected String lastFilter = "";

public SearchDialogAdapater(String[] bs, int[] bIds, Activity cont) {
this.stackBeaches = new Stack<String[]>();
this.stackBeachesIds = new Stack<int[]>();
this.stackBeaches.push(bs);
this.stackBeachesIds.push(bIds);
this.context = cont;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
filter(newText);
this.listView.setAdapter(this);
return true;
}

public void filter(String search) {
// no longer valid the previous selected, must clean selections
selectedPosition = -1;
lastView = null;
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
// hitted "backspace"
if (search.length() < lastFilter.length()) {
    if (stackBeaches.size() > 1) {
    stackBeaches.pop();
    stackBeachesIds.pop();
    }
    lastFilter = search;
    return;
}

// filter
ArrayList<String> filtBs = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> filtBsIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < stackBeaches.peek().length; i++) {
    String beach = new String(stackBeaches.peek()[i]);

    if (Pattern
        .compile(Pattern.quote(search), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
        .matcher(beach).find()) {
    filtBs.add(beach);
    filtBsIds.add(stackBeachesIds.peek()[i]);
    }
}

String[] beaches = new String[filtBs.size()];
int[] ids = new int[filtBsIds.size()];
int size = filtBs.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ids[i] = filtBsIds.remove(0);// head
    beaches[i] = filtBs.remove(0);
}

stackBeachesIds.push(ids);
stackBeaches.push(beaches);

lastFilter = search;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
    String beach = stackBeaches.peek()[position];

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_item, null);
    TextView txtBeach = (TextView) convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.dialBeach);
    txtBeach.setText(beach);
}

if (position == selectedPosition)// the same color below
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(128, 0, 64, 192));

return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return stackBeachesIds.peek()[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return stackBeaches.peek().length;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
return stackBeaches.peek().length == 0;
}

private View lastView;
private int selectedPosition = -1;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
    int position, long arg3) {
// some color...
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(128, 133, 181, 255));
selectedPosition = position;
if (lastView != null)
    lastView.setBackground(null);
lastView = view;

((SurfApplication) context.getApplication()).setBeachId(stackBeachesIds
    .peek()[position]);

if (!dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).isEnabled())
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
}

protected AlertDialog dialog;

public void setDialog(AlertDialog dial) {
this.dialog = dial;
this.listView = dialog.getListView();
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
((ProgressBar) context.findViewById(R.id.pBar))
    .setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
int beachId = stackBeachesIds.peek()[selectedPosition];
String beach = stackBeaches.peek()[selectedPosition];

// do something... Here I am creating a new Intent and starting
// the new activity within my context
}
```

}

Same methods are not here because they return null or do nothing at all.
Sorry for long post, but I need to answer this properly.

Thank you all and I hope someone find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter needs to implement [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) or extend from an adapter class that does. Adapters that already implement this interface, like ArrayAdapter, should do the filtering automatically for you.

Just call Adapter.getFilter().filter(...); with the value from the search view.