# Android:Is it possible to create a pop up window over a dialogbox

Tags: android

I want to create a pop up window from my dialog with out closing dialog.
While I create pop up window from dialog.The pop up window comes under the dialog and can't see that.Is there a way for create a popup window over dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is starting an activity as a dialog like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog) and in that activity you should be able to start a normal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can call/create another alert dialog inside this dialog and this will appear above the current one