# Multi line edittext with imeOptions="actionDone" does not work in an Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, textview

I want the edittext to be "multiline" at the same time need an "Done" button on the softKeyBoard to hide the softKeyBoard. I have the following code

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/etMultiLineDone"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:lines="3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

When I try the above code in

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); It works as expected

But when I try the same textview in a Custom Dialog it does not give the same functionality.

```
android:scrollHorizontally="false" - not working
android:inputType="textImeMultiLine" - not working
android:imeOptions="actionDone" - working
android:lines="3" - not working

    Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
    d.setTitle("dialog");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    d.show();
```

Help/ suggestions much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Which functionality is different? Is it lacking the multi-line or lacking the done-button, both, or something else different?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the details. please have a look. thank you

Comment: Experts... Any suggestions please.  Thank you

Comment: I'm thinking it may be a limitation of Dialog, but I couldn't find anything to confirm it. I don't think it should make a difference, but you could try removing the `LinearLayout` or create the `EditText` all in code. You could also try using `AlertDialog` and `setView` instead of `Dialog`. I don't think any of that should actually make a difference, but It may be possible.

Comment: Alternatively, it would be a bit more complex, because you'd have to make a new activity, but you can make an activity show as a Dialog and then set whatever you want to it. You would just add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to the `<activity>` tag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog

Comment: Thanks for that, I will try it but the thing is i have around 20 dialogs where i gather form information.

Comment: This seems to be the case for any type of activity, not just for Dialog. As soon as you tell Android that it's a multiline textedit, out goes everything else.