# Dialog from GCM not wakingUp the App

Tags: android, dialog, push-notification

I get push notifications, using this message create a Dialog to get the availability. Here I get push notification in Dialog form if the app is already open, if the app is not open, push notification comes and Dialog is not coming, How may I get the Dialog even the app is not open. Here is my Code.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);            
        String[] msg = newMessage.split(",");
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(msg[0]);
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(msg[1]);
        glat = msg[0];
        glon = msg[1];
        ambNo = msg[3];
        currIncId = msg[4];
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());            
         if(newMessage!=null)
            {
            showAlertDialog(context, msg[2]+" AT", getMyLocationAddress(latitude, longitude), false);
            return;
            }
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
```

and this is my Dialog Code:

```
    public void showAlertDialog(final Context context, String title, String message,
        Boolean status) 
{   
    dist = String.valueOf(distanceFrom(lat, lon, latitude, longitude));
    Log.i("DISTANCE TO MES FOM AMB", dist);
    final GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(context);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);        
    alertDialog.setTitle(title); 
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("RESPOND", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {      

            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){                      
                    stat = ServerUtilities.updatestatus(context, ambNo, String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()), "1", currIncId);
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;                   
                }
            };
             mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
             Intent mrAc = new Intent(context,MapRouteActivity.class);
             startActivity(mrAc);
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("DECLINE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {     
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    ServerUtilities.updatestatus(context, MainActivity.ambNo, MainActivity.glat, MainActivity.glon, "0",MainActivity.currIncId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;                               
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);

        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });        
    final AlertDialog dlg = alertDialog.create();        
    alertDialog.show();
    // Showing Alert Message
    //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.counter);
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            dlg.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
            t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT); // after 2 second (or 2000 miliseconds), the task will be active.
}
```

hope to get some good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogs need to have an Activity content. Just giving the application content doesn't work. You will need to start an Activity that looks like a dialog. See [Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)