# AppCompatActivity as a dialog without title

Tags: android, dialog, android-appcompat

I have an `Activity` inherited from `AppCompactActivity`. in manifest for activity set theme:

```
<style name="Theme.custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

When I run activity, it shows as a dialog, but title is shown! i try `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` and  `RequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` but title still displayed. Please let me know, What is wrong?

---

Edit

I solve it, only change `android:windowNoTitle` to  `windowNoTitle`! because i am use AppCompactActvity!

Comment: This is happening for me too. It remains even when I add a toolbar as the action bar. Seems like some kind of bug to me. You can set the title string as an empty string, but it's still there, so it affects the centering.

Comment: Add your edit as an answer and accept it, I nearly missed this in the edit :)

Comment: supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) working for me. When this is first sattement in activity's onCreate() method

Comment: @Harsh I think your answer is the right solution.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If you are having `AppCompatActivity` then the following won't work

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

The simple way is to set it in the `style.xml` file.

```
<style name="mytheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

> It is `name="windowNoTitle"`, not `name="android:windowNoTitle"`

If you want to remove it programmatically then add the following in `onCreate()`

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Careful, it is "windowNoTitle" not "android:windowNoTitle"

Comment: < It is name="windowNoTitle", not name="android:windowNoTitle" >
Thanks bro

Answer (score 7):

AppCompatActivity is different than Activity and has its own features. For the same purpose, you can simply use -

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

You can look up the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity#supportrequestwindowfeature)

Note: Add this before `setContentView()` to avoid crash.

Answer (score 1):

Set below style in your style.xml

```
<style name="customDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

then set this theme in your activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".yourDailogActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    **android:theme="@style/customDialogTheme"**
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Should keep nothing over Activity title. if following these steps activity title will be hidden.

**style.xml:**

```
    </style>
        <style name="MyTitledActivityDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

**manifiest.xml:**

```
 <activity
            android:name="YouActivity" 
            android:theme="@style/MyTitledActivityDialogTheme" />
```

**YourClass.java:**

after `setContentView(R.layout.xyz)` like this

```
  setContentView(R.layout.xyz);
  if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
      getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score -2):

please use the request window feature before `setContentView()` as below

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score -4):

Should keep nothing over `<string name="app_name"></string>`.so when you run your activity it will show dialog with "NO Title".

string.xml:

```
         <resources>
               <string name="app_name"></string>
               <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
               <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
        </resources>
```

Comment: Afaik the default title is the activity's label (which often refers to app_name), but it is not a good solution to just use an empty string as activity label.