# Dialog theme for AppCompat Activity with No title bar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I need a dialog theme for an Activity and for `Fragments` pushed to it.Below is the style I applied to Activity

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

I have toolbar set as support action bar in activity.But it is showing an extra title bar with app name in it above toolbar.How to avoid this?Please help.

I tried `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NOTITLE)` ,but it has no effect.I tried to use `DialogFragment` and set           `getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` which also has no effect.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppCompatActivity as a dialog without title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184031/appcompatactivity-as-a-dialog-without-title)

Answer (score 5):

This code is working fine. For Remove Title Bar from Activity extending **ActionBarActivity** or **AppcompatActivity** with Dialog Theme.

Add the code your **values-style** folder and create your custom theme.

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Add code your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity
            android:name="<YourActivityName>"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyDialog" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This code only helps me to solve the problem.

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra title is the activity's label, so you can try this code which is working for me.

```
<activity
      android:label=""
      android:name=".DialogActivity"
      android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"
      ></activity>
```