# Display an ActionBarCompat Activity as a dialog

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I have an Activity inherited from AppCompactActivity. in manifest for activity set theme:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.CameraSettingsActivity2"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
```

but the activity still displays in a fullscreen instead of dialog window.
I have been trying different themes such as ..

```
Theme.AppCompat.Dialog
Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert
Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth
```

none of them seems work.the activity still like this

[image]

Comment: Could you please paste your `style.xml` file here?

Comment: Try other style http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog

Answer (score 0):

try using this style `<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>`