# Why Soft keyboard does not work inside a web view which is inside a Dialog Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, webview, android-dialogfragment

In one of my activities there is button which pressing this button opens up a dialog fragment and inside this dialog fragment a web view appears. I use this web view for getting users information for an online store, but when the form loads on the web view, and I want to enter information soft keyboard does not come up.
Displaying the web view in another activity is okay and everything is working fine and I can enter the data.

My main activity which calls the dialog fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InformationDialog44.InformationDialogInfo {

Activity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    activity=this;


    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.showButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InformationDialog44 dialog=new InformationDialog44();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"parvaz-tag");
        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is the main layout(content_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="ir.parvaz.uitests.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/showButton"
    android:text="Show Dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the fragment code:

```
public class InformationDialog44  extends DialogFragment {
InformationDialog44 myself; 

InformationDialogInfo listener;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog2,null);
    builder.setView(view);
    WebView myWebView=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
       {
           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return true;
           }
           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
               Log.i("parvaz-uitests","URL is: "+url);

           }
       }
    );

    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    myself=this;
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    return builder.create();
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        listener=(InformationDialogInfo)activity;
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e)
    {
        Log.e("parvaz-error","Implement InformationDialogInfo. ");
        dismiss();
    }
}
public interface InformationDialogInfo
{
    void onOKClick(InformationDialog44 informationDialog);
    void onCancelClick(InformationDialog44 informationDialog);
}
}
```

Is there any restriction(probably for security reasons) to not allowing the keyboard on web view in dialog fragments?

Answer (score 0):

It seems no one has a straight answer. I couldn't solve the problem in this way, but the simplest way is to show your activity as a dialog as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog).

But in my case I had to replace the style name with:                                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"