# WhatsApp's new quick reply option, How it works?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, whatsapp

I'm trying to get a text input from the user after he clicks a notification action button.

The problem is that I'm using  a custom notification layout so the button is implemented by RemoteView and not by Notification.Action class, so I can't use RemoteInput.

So I was thinking to do something like WhatsApp's new quick reply option but I can't figure out how they have managed to do it...
Any ideas about that?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank ahead

Comment: it's just an `Activity` with a `Dialog` theme. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog (very old question but the principle is the same.)

Comment: launch an Activity on tap of notification with smaller size of activity.

Comment: ‎Thanks! I overlooked those options.. I thought about opening an activity from the service but it's much more sensible to open it from the notification!