# How to create a popout layout on top of other application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know how to express the name of this design technique, but please view the images below.

This is like the "chathead" of facebook messenger, when you click on chathead, it will show a layout right at the position of chathead, and then you can interact with that application via textview or button. When you click outside the layout it will collapse to become a chathead.

[image: The blue section is on top of other app (as browser)]

[image: r]

[image: r]

[image: r]

(Note: it's not duplicate, I looked everywhere on the internet before decide to ask this question).

Comment: Isn't that just like a Custom Dialog?

Comment: no, not a Custom Dialog

Comment: Then you better describe it more than just providing an image. Since that alone doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a popup window in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498605/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-android)

Comment: Thanks Ironman but it's not duplicate, i found every where on the internet before decide to ask this question to get 2 votes down. It's like "chathead" of facebook messenger, when you click to chathead, he will show a layout right on the position of chathead, and then you can interact with that application via textview or button.. When you click outsite the layout he will collapse to become a chathead icon.

Comment: http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/

Comment: thanks Kaushik, i know that tutorial, but i don't know how to deal with the popout dialog when you clicked the chathead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dialog themed Activity, which is an Activity but acts like a dialog.

```
<activity android:name="PopActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog) for details about how to create a dialog themed Activity.

Comment: not working, Theme.Dialog only work when you are in your application context, but when you are in another app, when you click chathead, nothing will happen, no dialog will display on top of another application