# Using Activity as a Dialog in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to use activity as a dialog, and I have done the following, but still it shows as an activity rather than dialog. I wonder what I am missing or doing wrong?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
   android:name="AboutView"
   android:theme="@style/Dialog">
</activity>
```

**Themes.xml**

```
<style name="Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**AboutView.cs**

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.MainViewContainer)]
[Activity(Label = "AboutView", Theme = "@style/Dialog")]
[Register("views.AboutView")]
public class AboutView : MvxFragment<AboutViewModel>
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.AboutView, null);
        return view;
    } 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog

Answer (score 0):

You're only specifying that the Activity's theme should inherit from Dialog's theme. The `AboutView` class still inherits from `MVXFragment`, which isn't a Dialog.

I'm not too familiar with Xamarin's class structure, but you'll need to ensure that the `AboutView` class inherits from Xamarin's version of a Dialog.

In Android studio it would be the `DialogFragment` class. You could start looking there.

Answer (score 0):

I think `MvxDialogFragment` is exactly what you're looking for. Here you have an [example](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/Frags/Dialog/NameDialogFragment.cs) how to use it