# How to make a dialog like this example?

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog, material-design

How to make a dialog like this example? (On the RIGHT)

[image]

If you look close, the dialog overlap the status bar and it has a very tiny margin from smartphone border...

How can I do this?

Comment: You tried creating a full screen activity, then setting the layout as you wish?

Comment: They're just two different view within a specified layout. Not familiar with android dev, but [this looks like it may point you in the right direction](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dialog. Try to create a custom Activity as Dialog with some views. I hope it helps you.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog

[Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

Comment: Full screen dialog dont overlap the statusbar.