# how to remove actionbar from dialog activity android

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-actionbar, themes

i have a dialog activity and want to remove the action bar from it , and anther dialog activity but just want to change the color of its action bar >>

i tried to change the theme and style but nothing  change also.

```
 <style name ="Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>


</style>
```

and the other style is

```
 <style name ="coloredDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>


</style>
```

also i have tried to use

getSupportActionBar().hide()

but their some is  error then and the app is closed suddenly

Comment: use this as parent : "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" maybe help you

Comment: no it will no help me because my activity theme is dialog

Comment: do you assign this theme to your dialogActivity in manifest ?

Comment: this link help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22216966/4936833)

Comment: yes @dariushf but nothing change , thanks

Comment: Consider using a spell checker. Proof-read your posts. `but their some is error then and the app is closed suddenly` ma be _but there is some error and then the app is closed suddenly_ as well as _but then there is some error and the app is closed suddenly_.