# findNavController and isolated fragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I launch a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` from the main fragment with the show function (navigation component can't start DialogFragments).

Now in the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` I have a button to move to a detail activity.

I have the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` defined in the graph (isolated) and it points to the detail activity.

But when I try to navigate, it can't find the navController. Is it possible to pass the navController to this isolated fragment?

MainFragment to Detail is working
DialogFragment to Detail is not working.

I tried:
- findNavController: navigation is not set
- activity.findNavController(...)

[image]

Comment: **MainFragment to Detail is working DialogFragment to Detail is not working.** It won't work because you opened it using `show` function.

You need to start with navigation-component to continue with it.

If you used `show` function` you better continue with it, Unless you choose the workaround I suggest in my answer below.

Comment: @IbrahimAli all the animation I used for it will work?

Comment: see how to set animation using nav-comp https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions

Comment: @IbrahimAli I will try it in some days (I have to travel tomorrow) I will post the result

Answer (score 1):

**But when I try to navigate, it can't find the navController**. That's how navigation-component work.

**Is it possible to pass the navController to this isolated fragment?** I hope you will not going with that, replacing navController is not the perfect solution for your case.

What to do?

You can have new `nav.xml` with new parent activity and the (isolated) fragment as child, and navigate from the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to (isolated) fragment-activity.

Otherwise, I don't see any problems that prevent you from adding related fragments in one `nav.xml`.

Also you may need to obey for navigation-component contract, don't use `show()` function while using navigation-component, you may miss some advantages here!

You really don't need show function see:-

[Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

Explanation:-

You can have a parent activity and set it's theme as Dialog, so all fragments (inside the `nav.xml`) will be dialogs..

I used this trick in one of my apps before.

Comment: I have already a nav.xml for the detail activity. So I have to change the bottomsheetdialog from the main graph to the detail graph?

Comment: @JavierSegoviaCordoba Indeed that won't fix your problem.

Comment: I have to use show(), it is not possible to use DialogFragment without it

Comment: @JavierSegoviaCordoba **it is not possible to use DialogFragment without it** not true. you can use it without show function.

Comment: What about this in your fragment: (getActivity() as MyActivity).findNavController

Comment: @JavierSegoviaCordoba Well, I used it in my app, but I opened the activity as dialog, so all child fragment will be dialogs...

Comment: @PedroMassango it says me the navigation "name" is unknown to this NavController

Comment: @IbrahimAli but I didn't want to have a lot of dialogs

Comment: @JavierSegoviaCordoba You don't need to have a lot of dialogs, you only need that for the fragment you opened as dialog, i.e: assume you have `dialogs_nav.xml` and in it's activity you can check which fragment will opened by passing `navArgs` and open `NavDialogActivity` from any where. 

I tried this way before, no problem with it.

Comment: @IbrahimAli I added the nav graph