# how to show custom dialog box when android application receives notification

Tags: android

popup message feature like whats app, caller id like the true caller, I am trying to make the same thing.

I tried using a broadcast receiver but I do not know how to show the dialog box when a broadcast receives a notification.

a pop-up message like WhatsApp shows when a notification arrives on a phone.

Comment: use Intent to start DialogActivity to appear like a DialogBox

Comment: I want that dialog when my app is closed or is in background. it is possible using intent ??

Comment: Yes. TrueCaller and many other applications does that

Comment: could you be able to share a code ??

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979631/4079010

Comment: not working....

Comment: Care to tell why?

Comment: when notification hits to the phone, it opens mainactivity and then show dialog

Comment: You were telling about `broadcast receiver ` not on the notification click

Comment: as I said in the previous comment, Main activity opens without any click on the notification.

Comment: Yes, because you've set `mainactivity` as launcher screen. In the `mainactivity` before `setContentView` method calling check if the `intent` has extra parameters as per your requirement. If yes, then finish the current activity and start `DialogActivity`.

Comment: thank you, sir, @RahulKhurana it is working now.

Comment: I have posted it as a answer

Comment: @abhishekghatge Can you please share how you did that?. I need to open DialogBox when App receive firebase push notification without clicking on notification and the app is closed.  Ex=> Truecaller Flash message. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `mainactivity` as a launcher screen. In the `mainactivity` before **setContentView** method calling check if the `intent` has extra parameters as per your requirement. If yes, then finish the current activity and start `DialogActivity`.