# How to show an Activity as a dialog box rather than a new screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am pretty new to this. I made 2 Activities. From Activity A I want to be able to open Activity B as a dialog window instead of it taking over the screen. I figured out how to make a dialog, but it seems its functionality needs to be programmed into the same Activity Java file. I want to keep my code separate.

Is there a way to show a dialog window that contains another activity along with all of it's coded functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest manifest file define your activity like this :

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true" />
```

and If you want your activity to not be cancelable when the user clicks outside it just add the following line in your Activity.Java file inside onCreate method :

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Was I correct in assuming that I should add to the already existing activity tag?

Comment: I got a crash, but turns out I guess I have to use "Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" instead of "Theme.Dialog." I don't like that it made it a dark theme though. I'll have to play around with it.

Comment: yes sir using Theme.AppCompat.Dialog will work fine for you, if you don't like the dark theme you can try another one

Answer (score 3):

Try the following for the activity :
In the activity,set the Theme by calling

`setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_DialogTheme)`

and create a corresponding style :

```
<style name="AppTheme.DialogTheme" 
parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize">
    <!-- removing the dialog's action bar -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">400dp</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">400dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this as a percentage of the screen, rather than a fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

Set you activity B theme from manifest.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to make some changes in the Manifest.

you can refer to this because your question has already been asked:

[android activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)